# How do I keep btn-group contained inside the well?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a problem where the btn-group goes outside the well.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="well">
                <form>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                                <button type="button"class="btn btn-small">Test1</button>
                                 <button type="button"class="btn btn-small">Test2</button>
                                 <button type="button"class="btn btn-small">Test3</button>
                                 <button type="button"class="btn btn-small">Test4</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!--span3-->
        <div class="span9">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test></td>
                        <td>Test></td>
                        <td>Test></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div><!--span9-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/FRJJD/

I came up with this solution which works:

.btn-group {
    white-space: normal;
}

However, that solution does not work for IE. The other option is to have the responsive design to re-align before the btn-group overshoot. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
~J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N/M I figured this out. Setting the input with class of "span12" will keep the input stretches inside the well.